# Screen video and audio capture library for .NET

Tags: .net, screen-recording

We will be creating a Windows desktop application that does a screen video capture with audio and we need a .NET library with the following criteria:

- It should be able to capture and record screen activity with audio as an MP4 video with H.264 encoding.
- It can be free or paid, as long as we don't need to acknowledge that we use them, and we are not restricted from selling our product without showing the entire world our source code.
- Should work for Windows 7 systems and up, and compatible with .NET 3.5

I've taken a look at [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), and while it does everything we need functionality-wise, the L/GPL license is too restrictive for our taste.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia Capture SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/capture). The LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK contains .NET libraries which leverage either Microsoft's DirectShow or Media Foundation libraries so they are compatible with any Windows versions that are still supported by Microsoft.

With the LEADTOOLS Multimedia Capture SDK, you can capture the live screen using the [LEAD Screen Capture filter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/multimedia/filters/leadscreencapturefilter(2.0).html).

You can also capture the audio from an audio device at the same time using the LEADTOOLS [CaptureCtrl](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/multimedia/mm/leadtools.multimedia~leadtools.multimedia.capturectrl.html) to connect to the audio device.

These captured audio and video streams can be saved using many different types of encodings including [H264](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia/h264) and can be saved to many different [file formats](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/main/api/multimediaformats.html) including MP4.

We also have online [tutorials](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/multimedia/to/leadtools.topics.multimedia~leadtools.topics.multimedia.creatingadirectshowcaptureapplication.html) showing how this would be done using the LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK.

Just as a disclaimer. I work for the company that wrote this library.